# What's the difference between Gradle's TaskExecutionListener and its TaskActionListener?

Tags: gradle

What's the difference between http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionListener.html and http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskActionListener.html? I guess the root question is, "What's the difference between a task executing and a task performing its actions?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When executing a task, it does more than just perform the actions -- and if the task is up-to-date, it doesn't even perform the actions at all.

Consider the following script, where we have two tasks with two actions each as well as an `outputs.upToDateWhen` closure. Task a is never considered up-to-date, while task b is always considered up-to-date:

```
task a {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { println "a - upToDateWhen"; false }
    doLast { println "a.1" }
    doLast { println "a.2" }
}

task b {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { println "b - upToDateWhen"; true }
    doLast { println "b.1" }
    doLast { println "b.2" }
}

gradle.addListener(new TaskExecutionListener() {
    void beforeExecute(Task task) {
        println "beforeExecute of $task"
    }
    void afterExecute(Task task, TaskState state) {
        println "afterExecute of $task"
    }
})

gradle.addListener(new TaskActionListener() {
    void beforeActions(Task task) {
        println "beforeActions of $task"
    }
    void afterActions(Task task) {
        println "afterActions of $task"
    }
})
```

On the first invokation of `gradle a b`, you get the following output:

```
$ gradle a b
:a
beforeExecute of task ':a'
a - upToDateWhen
beforeActions of task ':a'
a.1
a.2
afterActions of task ':a'
afterExecute of task ':a'
:b
beforeExecute of task ':b'
b - upToDateWhen
beforeActions of task ':b'
b.1
b.2
afterActions of task ':b'
afterExecute of task ':b'
```

Since it is the first execution, actions for both tasks are performed. Still, you can see that `TaskExecutionListener.beforeExecute` is invoked before the `upToDateWhen` check, while `TaskActionListener.beforeActions` is invoked after the check.

On second execution, it gets more interesting:

```
$ gradle a b
:a
beforeExecute of task ':a'
a - upToDateWhen
beforeActions of task ':a'
a.1
a.2
afterActions of task ':a'
afterExecute of task ':a'
:b
beforeExecute of task ':b'
b - upToDateWhen
:b UP-TO-DATE
afterExecute of task ':b'
```

Here you can notice that the `TaskExecutionListener` methods are invoked for both tasks, while the `TaskActionListener` methods are not invoked for task b since the task is considered up-to-date and its actions are skipped.